# Kotlin obsever not executing changes on view, after re-entering the fragment

Tags: kotlin, android-view, observers

So im trying to set an observer and update fragment views depending on the response.
The thing is when i first enter the fragment all works good, but if go back to other fragment, and re-enter the fragment it triggers the observe, and even executes the code, but doesn't change nothing on view.

```
    override fun onStart() {
        bindObservers()
        loadUI()
        super.onStart()
    }
```

```
private fun loadUI() {

        /**
         *  Load Variables
         *
         *  Note:
         *      This Should be loaded as soon as possible in loadUI
         *
         * */

        goalsViewModel.getFitnessModel()

        
        /**
         *  General
         * */


    }
```

```
private fun bindObservers() {

        /**
         * Ideal Weight
         */

        goalsViewModel.getFitnessModelLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { networkResultEvent ->
            networkResultEvent.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                when (it) {
                    is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                        fitnessReport = it.data!!

                        binding.minWeightRecommendedValue.text = fitnessReport.idealWeight.lowerLimit.toString() + " Kg"
                        binding.maxWeightRecommendedValue.text = fitnessReport.idealWeight.upperLimit.toString() + " Kg"

                        binding.maintainWeightValue.text = "${fitnessReport.maintain.calories.toString()} Calories"
                        binding.gain05Value.text = fitnessReport.plusHalf.calories.toString() + " Calories"
                        binding.gain1Value.text = fitnessReport.plus.calories.toString() + " Calories"

                        binding.lose05Value.text = fitnessReport.minusHalf.calories.toString() + " Calories"

                        if (fitnessReport.minus.calories == null)
                            binding.lose1.isEnabled = false
                        else
                            binding.lose1Value.text = fitnessReport.minus.calories.toString() + " Calories"


                        teste()
                    }
                    is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                        // Handle error if needed
                    }
                    is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
                        // Handle loading state if needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun teste(){
        binding.fragmentGoalCreateGoalWeightPb.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.fragmentGoalCreateGoalWeightParentCl.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
```

I've tried to put breakpoint on teste() and it does execute the code in it.

I also tried to:

```
    override fun onStart() {
        bindObservers()
        loadUI()
        teste()
        super.onStart()
    }
```

and it does change the View, so i think its the observer but i dont why or how to fix it.